# ButtonView no se muestra correctamente

Tags: android, xml

En android studio acabo de insertar un ButtonView en un Relative layout. Aunque en la vista previa se ve bien, al darle al play sale comprimido:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

código:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.xxx.xxx.xxx"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
    >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    </WebView>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_engranaje" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema creo que lo estás teniendo al cargar la imagen del botón, que no se está cargando.

Prueba a cambiar `app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_engranaje"` por  `android:src="@mipmap/ic_engranaje"`

Puedes echarle un ojo a esta pregunta de [SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40624625/3683321) en el que explica la diferencia que existe en utilizar `app:srcCompat` vs `android:src` que básicamente reside en que el que estás utilizando se utiliza para insertar dibujos vectoriales mientras que el que te sugiero se utiliza para insertar un drawable.